# Is there a way to append year part to the syslogs in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I am new to ELK stack . Currently working on syslogs which are of the form :

`Apr 26 12:20:02 localhost systemd[1]: Starting system activity accounting tool...`

The grok pattern using is as below:

```
        grok {
            match => {
                "message" => [
                   "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_date}\s+%{DATA:node}\s+%{DATA:component_name}\[%{NUMBER:pid}\]\:\s+%{GREEDYDATA:log_message}"]
```

I need to parse these logs kibana in format below with syslog_date having the current year append to it .

Current Format:

```
  "log_message" => "Starting system activity accounting tool...",
  "@timestamp" => August 28th 2019, 23:49:53.014,
  "node"        => "localhost",
  "@version"   => "1",
  "host"       => "localhost.localdomain",
  "pid"        => "1",
  "message"    => "Apr 26 12:20:02 localhost systemd[1]: Starting system activity accounting tool...",
  "type"       => "stdin",
  "component_name"  => "systemd",
  "SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_date"  => "Apr 26 12:20:02"
}
```

Required format :

```
  "log_message" => "Starting system activity accounting tool...",
  "@timestamp" => August 28th 2019, 23:49:53.014,
  "node"        => "localhost",
  "@version"   => "1",
  "host"       => "localhost.localdomain",
  "pid"        => "1",
  "message"    => "Apr 26 12:20:02 localhost systemd[1]: Starting system activity accounting tool...",
  "type"       => "stdin",
  "component_name"  => "systemd",
  "SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_date"  => "Apr 26 2019 12:20:02"
}
```

Can anyone help on it? Or any other way which can fulfill this scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the "current" year according to the the @timestamp field in logstash using

```
mutate { add_field => { "dateWithYear" => "%{[syslog_date]} %{+YYYY}" } }
```

However, there are going to be times (just after midnight on December 31st) when that is the wrong year. The date filter has [some handling](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-date/pull/4) for this, and there has been discussion about [changing](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-date/issues/51) that.

Comment: It worked with few changes :
``` mutate { add_field => { "dateWithYear" => "%{syslog_date} %{+YYYY}" } }

Comment: Yeah, that was a copy and paste error which I have fixed.